# How to show that $\sum_{j\leq \sqrt{i}}6^j\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i-j}\to 0 \text{ as } i\to \infty$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> How to show that 
>   $$\sum_{j\leq \sqrt{i}}6^j\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i-j}\to 0 \text{ as } i\to \infty$$

Notice that

$$\sum_{j\leq \sqrt{i}}6^j\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i-j}\leq \sum_{j\leq \sqrt{i}}6^{\sqrt{i}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i-\sqrt{i}}=(\sqrt{i}-j)6^{\sqrt{i}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i-\sqrt{i}}$$

But how to prove that the last term tends to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last expression should probably read as $ \sqrt{i}6^{\sqrt{i}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i-\sqrt{i}}$. And this equals $\sqrt{i} 3^{\sqrt{i} }\left(\frac14\right)^{\sqrt{i}}=\sqrt{i}\left(\frac34\right)^{\sqrt{i}}$. Since $\lim_{k\to\infty} kq^k=0$ if $\vert q\vert<1$, the assertion follows.

*Edit*: See the comment by https://math.stackexchange.com/users/602049/john-omielan below. I'm ashamed for this terrible mistake in calculations fractions.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{i}6^{\sqrt{i}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i-\sqrt{i}} = \sqrt{i}\left(6^{\sqrt{i}}\right)\left(2^{\sqrt{i}-i}\right) = \sqrt{i}\left(\frac{12^{\sqrt{i}}}{2^i}\right)$. This is different than what you say it's equal to, but this expression's value also goes to $0$ as $i \to \infty$.